# Typescript argument passing

Tags: typescript

While programming in Typescript, I got a question about the situation like below. 
 When I pass an argument with an object with the same name as the parameter defined in the function signature, Typescript understands it, otherwise it doesn't.

What is this feature of Typescript called? Is it also type of a type inference?

[image]

Comment: [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: This is not a typescript feature. Its javascript feature and its property shorthand. `{bbar}` means an object with the property named `bbar` but your function expects an object with the property named `bar`

Comment: `What is this feature of Typescript called?` Type checking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TypeScript is simply checking the argument you are passing to `func`. You defined `func` as a function that takes a parameter which is an object with a key named `bar`.

The first and second calls of `func` work because the argument passed matches the condition, but the third one causes an error, since the object passed does not have `bar` property, but has `bbar` property.